# How to prevent LazyColumn reset position in Jetpack compose when navigating between bottom nav tabs?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(){
    val popularListState = rememberLazyListState()
    val viewModel: HomeViewModel = hiltNavGraphViewModel()
    val popularMovies: List<Movie> by viewModel.popularMoviesLiveData.observeAsState(emptyList())
    LazyColumn(
        state = popularListState
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(movies) { _, movie ->
            HomeMovieComponent(movie = movie)
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever navigate to other screen from the bottom nav the lazy column resets the scroll position to top

[Followed this guide to setup the bottom nav](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you select `BottomNavigationItem` your composable replaced by other composable and when you select back it reinitializes again. To restore previous composable use `saveState = true` and `restoreState = true` in your `BottomNavigationItem`.

```
BottomNavigationItem(
    icon = { /*Some Icon*/ },
    label = { /*Some Text*/ },
    selected = currentRoute == item.route,
    onClick = {
      navController.navigate(item.route) {
        // Put These line in your code.
        popUpTo(navController.graph.startDestinationId) {
          saveState = true
        }
        launchSingleTop = true
        restoreState = true
      }
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks brother, Didn't aware that documentation change

Comment: Had another issue when we navigate to different screen without bottom nav then it doesn't save states afterwards

Comment: use `navController.popBackStack()` instead of `navController.navigate(/*Some Route*/)`

Comment: literally the issue is with `collectAsLazyPagingItems() `. Sadly could not be able to fix it

Comment: @nabeel any luck with saving state when using collectAsLazyPagingItems() ?